# javascript object of object editing

Tags: javascript, object

I have the following code, which doesn't work.

```
var conversations = { };
conversations['5634576'].name = 'frank';
```

Apparently I cannot create objects inside objects. I wanted to use the conversation object to store arrays of objects to keep a history of messages client-side with localStorage to save space server side.

But apparently, I cannot even create variables inside the object, unless they already exist, like this:

```
var conversations = { 123: { name: 'test' } };
conversations[123].name = "frank";
```

But, since I will not know the IDs that will be used, I have no idea how workaround this problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: `var conversations = {}; conversations['5634576'] = {}; conversations['5634576'].name = 'frank';`, you can check if the second step is necessary using `if (!conversations.hasOwnProperty('5634576')) { /*..*/ }`

Comment: what a hassle.... well, thanks anyway!

Comment: Or `var conversations = { }; conversations['5634576'] = {name: 'frank'}`. *"what a hassle."*: well, what do you expect? You are trying to access the value at property `'5634576'`, which does not exist. Please read [MDN - Working with Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

Comment: but, when the user receives a new message, the object is re-created, therefore rewriting it, with the string example you cannot see it but, imagine it being an array: it will be a problem.

Comment: @john: Only initialize the object/array/whatever if it does not exist yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do like this:

```
// Create an object
var conversations = {};

// Add a blank object to the object if doesn't already exist
if (!conversations.hasOwnProperty('5634576')) {
    conversations['5634576'] = {};
}

// Add data to the child object
conversations['5634576'].name = 'frank';
```

The object will look like this:

```
conversations{
    '5634576': {
        name : 'frank'
    }
}
```

**Update**

You can check if the element exist using `in`

```
if('5634576' in conversations) {
    // Exist
}
```

Comment: what about arrays? if i instantiate the array like this -> `conversations['5634576'].messages = []; conversations['5634576'].messages.push(message);` i will lose the previous messages. can I prevent this?

Comment: `conversations['5634576'] = conversations['5634576'] || {}; conversations['5634576'].messages = conversations['5634576'].messages || [];`

Comment: @john: Only do `conversations['5634576'].messages = [];` when `.messages` does not exit yet. Obviously you will loose any previous value when you assign a new value.

Comment: @johnsmith If you do `push`, you won't lose previous messages.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you can't add a variable to the index '5634576' because it is not still existing.

```
var conversations = { };
conversations['5634576'].name = 'frank';
```

You need to create it, then assign the valriable

```
var conversations = { };
conversations['5634576'] = {};
conversations.name = 'frank';
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the shortest possible way:

```
var conversations = {};
(conversations['5634576'] = {}).name = 'frank';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// build this how you were
conversations = {};

// if conversations[12345] is defined, use it:
// else set it to an object with the desired properties/methods
conversations["12345"] = conversations["12345"] || { name : "Frank", messages : [] };
conversations["12345"].messages.push(new_msg);
```

I'm assuming you're going to be doing this within a function, XHR or otherwise

```
conversations.add_message = function (msg) {
    var id = msg.conversation_id;
    conversations[id] = conversations[id] ||
                        conversations.new_conversation(msg.user_name); // returning a conversation object
    conversations[id].messages.push(msg);
};


conversations.new_conversation = function (name) {
    return { name : name, messages : [], etc : {} };
};
```